# Android: NullPointerException на элементы массива

Tags: android, java, исключения

Всем привет.

Есть сервис с задачей (Runnable) определить геолокацию, которая запущена в основном потоке приложения (runOnUiThread()). В сервисе инициализирован строковый массив, который будет содержать геолокацию. Инициализируется он в методе onCreate() сервиса, передается в класс LocationListener через параметры конструктора и там, когда геолокация определится, заполняется.

В другой activity я биндюсь к этому сервису, и по нажатию кнопки запускаю таймер с задачей:

```
@Override
public void run() {
    try {
        String[] locationData = serviceConnection.serviceLocation().locationData;
        if (locationData[0].isEmpty()) {
            Log.e("Tag", "locationData isEmpty");
            return;
        }
        else {
            Log.e("Tag", "locationData !isEmpty");
            //location = location(locationData);
            timer.cancel();
            dialogWait.dismiss();
        }
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
        timer.cancel();
        dialogWait.dismiss();
        Toast.makeText(context, toastTaskFail, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

Причем, задача выполняется так же в UI потоке:

```
TimerTask tTask = new TimerTask() {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        context.runOnUiThread(tTaskRun);
    }
};
```

Вот эта строчка срабатывает, присвоение ссылки на массив, находящийся в сервисе происходит хорошо:

```
String[] locationData = serviceConnection.serviceLocation().locationData;
```

Значит, ссылка не null. Но дальше, при проверки на пустоту элементов этого массива вылетает исключение NullPointerException:

> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):
> java.lang.NullPointerException 07-13
> 19:55:45.332: E/AndroidRuntime(3140):
>   at
> dangeroussection.functional.serviceuploadtoserver.GetLocation$1.run(GetLocation.java:86)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:725)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:153)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5299)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native
> Method) 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:833)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:600)
> 07-13 19:55:45.332:
> E/AndroidRuntime(3140):   at
> dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native
> Method)

Подскажите, в чем проблема?

Answer (score 2):

С чего вы взяли, что если строчка:

```
String[] locationData = serviceConnection.serviceLocation().locationData;
```

Срабатывает значит `locationData` не равен `null`?

Вставьте строку:

```
if(locationData!=null)
   Log.i(TAG, "Size of locationData="+locationData.length);
else
   Log.i(TAG, "locationData=null");
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло